# How to expand wildcards after substituting them into a filepath as arguments, in bash script?

Tags: bash, wildcard

I am currently trying to substitute arguments into a filepath

```
FILES=(~/some/file/path/${1:-*}*/${2:-*}*/*)
```

I'm trying to optionally substitute variables, so that if there are no arguments the path looks like `~/some/file/path/**/**/*` and if there is just one, it looks like `~/some/file/path/arg1*/**/*`, etc. However, I need the wildcard expansion to occur after the filepath has been constructed. Currently what seems to be happening is that the filepath is into FILES as a single filepath with asterisks.

The broader goal is to pass all subdirectories that are two levels down from the current directory into the `FILES` variable, unless arguments are given, in which case the first argument is used to pick a particular directory at the first level, the second argument for the second level.

edit:

This script generates directories and then grabs random files from them, and previously had `**` instead of `*`, however it still works, and correctly restricts the files to pull from when given arguments. Issue resolved.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir dir1 dir1/a
touch dir1/a/foo.txt dir1/a/bar.txt
cp -r dir1/a dir1/b
cp -r dir1 dir2

files=(./*${1:-}/*/*)

for i in {1..10}
do
    # Get random file
    nextfile=${files[$RANDOM % ${#files[@]} ]}

    # Use file
    echo "$nextfile" || break

    sleep 0.5
done

rm -r dir1 dir2
```

Comment: Which version of bash is this?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)`

Comment: `**` -- aka `globstar` -- is a 4.x feature (and, moreover, a 4.x feature that's turned off by default). It isn't available in bash 3.2 (which is utterly ancient, but Apple refuses to ship 4.x since it's licensed GPLv3).

Comment: As an aside, all-caps names for your own (as opposed to system-defined) variables is bad practice. Keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace, see the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html for a discussion of naming conventions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much... currently in my script there is a conditional that checks if there's no arguments and if so puts `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/**/**/*` into the (now renamed) `files` variable. That part of the script functions fine, so I assumed globstar was functioning, but it must have been doing so without the use of globstar. I assume bash 3.2 would interpret that filepath as `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/*/*/*` ?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducer that works standing alone -- ie. creates a file that *should* match, and then demonstrates it not matching? When I create something that should match, it actually does match. :)

Comment: ...and yes, 3.2 should just treat `**` as a single non-recursive `*`.

Comment: After your edit -- where's the bug? And why do you think that `files` doesn't have more than one entry? (Run `declare -p files` to see its contents).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, you've found my fundamental misunderstanding, haha, I assumed that `**` was needed to get all files in all subdirectories and that `echo` would print more than the first element if there was a list.

Comment: `echo "${files[@]}"` will print more than the first -- though I'd suggest `printf '%q\n' "${files[@]}"` for a less ambiguous format.

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- `globstar` **is** needed if you want to recurse through more directories than you're putting explicitly in your glob expression. Right now, it looks like the number you're putting in explicitly is enough for your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce this behavior.

```
$ files=( ~/tmp/foo/${1:-*}*/${2:-*}*/* )
$ declare -p files
declare -a files='([0]="/Users/chaduffy/tmp/foo/bar/baz/qux")'
```

---

To explain **why** this is expected to work: Parameter expansion happens before glob expansion, so by the time glob expansion takes place, content has already been expanded. See [lhunath's simplified diagram of the bash parse/expansion process](http://stuff.lhunath.com/parser.png) for details.

A likely explanation is simply that **your glob has no matches**, and is evaluating to itself for that reason. This behavior can be disabled with the `nullglob` switch, which will give you an empty array:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(~/some/file/path/${1:-*}*/${2:-*}*/*)
declare -p files
```

---

Another note: `**` only has special meaning in shells where `shopt -s globstar` has been run, and where this feature (added in 4.0) is available. On Mac OS X (without installation of a newer version of bash via MacPorts or similar), it doesn't exist; you'll want to use `find` for recursive operations. If your glob would only match if `**` triggered recursion, this would explain the behavior in question.